# Font Awesome Icons: common baseline

Tags: html, css, svg, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome 5.0.10 (SVG + JS) to render a few social media icons.

If I use the squared versions, they all share a common baseline and thus are aligned, but the non-squared are not, as you can see by looking at the distance between the svg box and the path in icons like these:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/facebook-f?style=brands

https://fontawesome.com/icons/linkedin-in?style=brands

I'm no SVG expert, so I'm trying to understand if there's some easy way to curb that lower empty space, and thus have icons all aligned to a common baseline.

Comment: you can adjust the viewbox of each one if you need

Comment: If you mean changing (through JS) the values of the viewBox attribute, that also seems to imply changing the rendered size of the icons, which is not what I'm after... 

Besides, if I were to do a per-icon work of adjustment, a pure-CSS solution (like the one proposed by mrcharlie) would be less of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't edit the font file directly (easily), you'll have to manually shift of on a per-icon basis, e.g.:

```css
.fa-linked-in {
  transform: translateY(1px);
}
```

```html
<i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

The reason it's not baseline-aligned is that it is centre-aligned since that's more useful in more cases.